# Google Maps Api V2 Unable to execute dex: Java heap space. Refreshing external archives (Blocked)

Tags: java, android, maps

I´m new in Android developing. I´m stuck doing a Maps V2 application. Actually I did manage to run my application and it worked fine in my cellphone. Then, I made some modification (added some buttons and stuff like that) and the next time I tried to run it, in the progress tab appeared "Refreshing external archives (Blocked: the user operation is waiting for background work to complete) and after 2-3 minutes it force closed with a dialog that says "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space". I have no idea what is the mistake I´m doin. When i run other applications in my workspace they seem to be running fine. Hope someone can help me!!

Thanks,

PD: tried to made other maps applications and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using maps api v2 first change to `-Xmx1024m` and followed the error "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit exceeded" or "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space Java heap space".

My solution was:

if you are using 32-bit eclipse is important: 
- In linux, minimum value `Xmx1500m` 
- In windows, minimum value `Xmx1100m`

finally my eclipse.ini was as follows:

```
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1200m
```